# Insert/Update into SQLite Database each second Android

Tags: android, sqlite, database-performance

I just wanted to know if it will take a lot of resources to update a field each second on my SQLite Database and how I can track it?

I need to decrement an "elapsed" field in my DB :

```java
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // My update DB Here ??
    }

    public void onFinish() {
    }
}.start();
```

My SQLite request will be as simple as that :

```sql
UPDATE table
SET column_1 = new_value_1
WHERE
table.id = id
```

Comment: should not take much resources.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Ok thank you and did you know how can i track it ?

Comment: track what exactly?

Comment: All transaction in db, for example know if the request take 1ms or more

Comment: store the system time before executing request, check it against time after executing request, log the difference somewhere

Comment: So as simple as that, Thank you !